# Upgraded java version to 17, spring boot version to 2.5.7 when running testcases for actuator/info geting 404. How to resolve?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-boot-actuator, java-17

how to resolve tried

```html
management:
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info"
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "
```

management:
endpoints:
jmx:
exposure:
include: "health,info"
web:
exposure:
include: "

Comment: Your example code seems to be truncated. Did you mean to set configuration property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"`?

Answer (score 0):

in case you'd like to expose **only** `/actuator/info`

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info
```

(you expose specific endpoints by adding comma separated values like:`info,health,metrics,mappings,prometheus`)

dont forget to add spring boot actuator starters

`build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  ...
}
```

or `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

(note - version not specified)